# Can a function be named default?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, keyword

I was creating a function in Visual Studio 2012 to check if an item was the default and went to call it `default()`. However, I noticed that when I finished and waited a couple of seconds, the name was no longer bolded and no Intellisense errors were shown. Intrigued, I tried it out:

```
void default(){}

int main() {
    default();
}
```

This code works on Visual Studio 2012 with both the regular compiler and the November 2012 CTP one, but does not compile on GCC 4.7.2 or on http://llvm.org/demo. I realize that `default` is used for both switches and for `= default` on some class members. VS2012 does not support the latter, but it obviously supports the former, and it does indeed complain if I change the function name to `delete`, `nullptr`, or `switch`, or `case`.

On GCC, I get this:

> error: expected unqualified-id before 'default'
>   In function 'int main()':
>   error: case label not within a switch statement
>   error: expected ':' before '(' token
>   error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Clang gives me this:

> error: expected unqualified-id
>   void default(){}
>   ........^

I'm obviously changing the name of it now, but is VS wrong in accepting this, or did it perhaps change specifically with the `= default` and `= delete` addition to the language? If VS doesn't support that, and that's the cause of the program being wrong, I could see why it accepts it.

I found this in the spec (C++11 § 6.1/2):

> Case labels and default labels shall occur only in switch statements.

Since it is not being used as a label, with the colon following it, I guess it could be argued that it's allowed, but then why would `case` compile? I'm guessing there's something more specific to function names, but I couldn't find it.

Are you allowed to name a function `default()`, and does the rule differ between C++03, and C++11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `default` identifier is reserved for use as a keyword:

> The identifiers shown in Table 4 are reserved for use as keywords (that is, they are unconditionally treated as keywords in phase 7) except in an *attribute-token*

Table 4<sup>†</sup> contains, among all other keywords, `default`.  VC++ is wrong to accept an identifier of `default` outside of an *attribute-token*, and a function name is not an *attribute-token*..

<sup>†</sup> It's Table 4 in C++11, but Table 3 in C++98 and 03. Nonetheless, they all contain `default`.

Comment: You could also include Table 5 (C++11) in this answer, although not strictly 'keywords' they are still reserved.

Comment: That sums it up pretty well, but do you have any idea at all why VS would accept this? It's a real pain to search because the search needs to include "default" (unless you find another that exhibits this behaviour), which causes the results of the search to be completely irrelevant.

Comment: @chris: Does it matter why VS lets it go? It's non-standard behavior; you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Of course it's a bad idea to rely on it, but there's usually a reason behind it. Otherwise, why wouldn't it be treated exactly the same as `case`, or any other keyword, depending on how you look at it?

Comment: @chris Does compiling with the `/Ze` option still allow it?

Comment: @sftrabbit, I presume you meant disabling language extensions, which shows up as `/Za`, but yes, that did it in, thanks. That really does make me wonder why they go out of their way to allow that, though.

Comment: @chris Yeah, pretty strange. Not exactly the nicest of extensions. Also: "Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard."

Comment: @sftrabbit, Yeah, it's a shame I have to keep them on, though, because certain Microsoft-made files rely on them.

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed. You can't use any C++ keywords in the declaration of functions or variables. No exceptions. This rule is the same in all C++ standards.